# How to get temporary Permesso di Soggiorno?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, italy, ryanair

I am renewing my Permesso di Soggiorno.

I want to travel to Germany for Christmas vacation to visit my sister, but I'm waiting for the renewal of my Permesso di Soggiorno to be complete

How to get temporary Permesso di Soggiorno?

Comment: You should ask this question on [Expatriates.SE].  You're much more likely to find someone there who knows the answer than here.

Comment: Question [is there](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) now.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [**Polizia di Stato d'Italia**](http://www.sicurincitta.it/articolo/10722)

> **Requirements for immigrants leaving Italy temporarily**
>
> Foreigners awaiting **renewal of their residence permits** can leave and re-enter Italy if they hold:
>
> - the receipt issued by Italian Post offices (Poste Italiane S.p.A) certifying the submission of the application for renewal of their residence permit or EC residence permit for long-term residents;
> - the expired residence permit;
> - their passport or other equivalent travel document .

Comment: But I read some articles about traveling to Schengen country is not allowed with this things. Thats why I'm searching for other ways. It is possoble to have a temporary Permesso di Soggiorno?. @Dorothy

Comment: You asked about a temporary Permesso; Italia doesn't issue a temporary document. Is the question whether you will have problems entering Germany? You're already within the Schengen Area.

Comment: The problem is I'm renewing my Permesso. So it is possible to go to Germany even if my Permesso is on process of renewing?. @Dorothy

Comment: Correct, and you can travel with the expired Permesso, the receipt from the post office when you sent your renewal, and your valid passport from your country of citizenship (all three).

Comment: But there is an article saying that "Moreover the journey cannot entail any transit (not even as a stop
over) through any of the Schengen countries; Namely: Austria, Belgio, Danimarca, Finlandia, Francia, Germania, Grecia, Italia, Lussemburgo, Paesi Bassi, Portogallo, Spagna, Svezia, Islanda, Norvegia, Slovenia, Estonia, Lettonia, Lituania, Polonia, Repubblica Ceca, Slovacchia, Ungheria e Malta." @Dorothy

Comment: You're looking at an article from 2009 on a random site on the internet; you're asking random strangers on this site. I should have asked; what is your citizenship?

Comment: Pilipino. @Dorothy